# PrintWriter output to jsp page inside body tag

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, httpresponse

This is the code to print to my jsp page. However I have other code in the page. When I call this function I want it to print the message right after where it is called. I can't check for sure because I am using xhtml negotiation, but I suspect it prints after the /html tag.

This is my function

```
public Print(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        try{
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("<p>haha</p>");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

This is where I call it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
<%@ page import="com.otrocol.app.*" %>
<%
    Print(request, response);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I think the result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
"haha"
```

This is what I want the response to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>  
    <body>
     "haha"
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: *This is what I think the result is*: why don't you tell us what the result actually is? Right-click in the browser page, choose "View page source", and see what the result is.

Comment: I cannot do that because my result page is just a xhtml error page

Comment: Then it can't be what you think it is. What does the error page say? What do your logs say?

Comment: You have my error there.. the page view thing would not work because it only shows the html for the error message. It say I get extra content at the end of document.. which means my text is printed after </html>. I was asking how tot get it to print inside <body> tag

Comment: I believe this is a good specific question: How to get PrintWriter to write inside the body tag. Whoever downgraded my question please give me the reason

Comment: Can you connect directly to the server from the command line via telnet or equivalent, execute the http protocol manually, and see the actual output being generated?

Comment: I'm getting a feeling that you're trying for a hack to let you switch to JSPs from existing Servlets. Hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSP uses its own PrintWriter, the JspWriter `out`. So pass this to the (static) function.
Otherwise you are taking a second writer, and with buffering everything goes haywire.

Also as output already did happen do not set the content type in the function.

At the top of the JSP is a nice location, also for the imports.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

When having *one* writer the function would print at the correct spot in the body.

Nice intuition about the cause. BTW begin a function name with a small letter.

Comment: You are a genius. I understand now. This is my first time using tomcat+jsp. Now I know I can't create 2 PrintWriters (the default jsp one and mine in the java class).

Comment: and also the function is just an example.. the real code is a actually a constructor, hence the capital letter.

Comment: Then let me thank for the reduction in code in the question. Some do not take the effort.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? I am trying to pass JspWriter as a parameter to my constructor. However I get error saying unable to find symbol JspWriter. I have included java.io.* and javax.servlet.* . In the documentation it says it is in javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter. How come I still get an error?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a *direct* answer to your question but I believe what you're doing will cause you nothing but pain even if you get it to work. You're not using the right tool for the job; creating custom JSP tags is a better option for writing to `JSP` from Java code.

---

Code example:

**register.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="custom" uri="/WEB-INF/custom-tags.tld" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
      <c:out value="${custom:printHaha()}" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom-tags.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<taglib version="2.0" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>2.0</jspversion>
    <shortname>custom-taglib</shortname>

    <uri>CustomTags</uri>

    <function>
        <name>printHaha</name>
        <function-class>com.yourpackage.Tags</function-class>
        <function-signature>
           java.lang.String print()
        </function-signature>
    </function>

    (...)
```

**Tags.class**

```
public class Tags {
    public static String print() {
        return "haha";
    }
}
```

---

More info on Tags: [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html)

Comment: This was useful. I will consider implementing it in the future. I just started with jsp. Trying to wrap my head around it. Although it is very hard without some easy to follow tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I din't check your code ... you can't do a out.print again using get writer in a jsp page ... because the response for this request is already committed by rendering the jsp

now to print something on asp you can do this any number of ways

1. print by expression tag

1. use out (which is an object the server creates)

   out.print("Blah...");

and more

to understand what happens to a jsp look into /work/catalina/blah.../

Comment: This is what I did.. just chose to simplify the code a bit. The function works.. it prints .. it just prints in the wrong place.

Comment: @VladOtrocol i re changed the answer, dint look at the print function

Answer (score 0):

There are two pages. The first one is the Main Page. This one performs some 
pseudo calcs.

Based on those calcs, either Success.jsp or Failure.jsp is returned.

This code will do what you wanted to have achieved.....

Even though as the others pointed out, there are more advanced techniques as of
late, still in order to dance, first you have to know the moves....

[image: a busy cat]

Primarily look at this 
    cObj.Print(request, response); in the 2nd jsp page.

JSP Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="rustler.Beans.Beany" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP and JavaBean</title>

        <%-- create an instance of Customer class --%>
        <jsp:useBean id="cObj" scope="request" class="rustler.Beans.Beany">

        <%-- Set the value of attribute such as CustID --%>
        <jsp:setProperty name="cObj" property="*" />
        </jsp:useBean>

    </head>
<body>

<%
            int x=cObj.setStoreCust();

            if(x>=1)
            {
        %>
                <jsp:forward page="Success.jsp" />
        <%

            }
            else
            {
        %>
                <jsp:forward page="Failure.jsp" />
        <%

            }

        %>

</body>
</html>
```

JSP Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="rustler.Beans.Beany" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Failure!</title>

<%-- create an instance of Customer class --%>
<jsp:useBean id="cObj" scope="request" class="rustler.Beans.Beany">

<%-- Set the value of attribute such as CustID --%>
<jsp:setProperty name="cObj" property="*" />


</jsp:useBean>

</head>
<body>


<%cObj.Print(request, response);%>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Bean

```
package rustler.Beans;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Beany implements Serializable
{

    public Beany()
    {

    }
        /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String custID;
        private String custName;
        private int qty;
        private float price;
        private float total;
        private int storeCust;

        public String getCustID() {
            return custID;
        }

        public void setJunk(String sStr)
        {
            //System.out.println("What a punk!");
            custName = sStr;//"What a punk!";           
        }       

        public void Print(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            try{
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("<p>haha</p>");
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public String prntJunk()
        {
            //System.out.println("What a punk!");
            return custName;//"What a punk!";           
        }

        public void setCustID(String custID) {
            this.custID = custID;
        }

        public String getCustName() {
            return custName;
        }

        public void setCustName(String custName) {
            this.custName = custName;
        }

        public int getQty() {
            return qty;
        }

        public void setQty(int qty) {
            this.qty = qty;
        }

        public float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public float getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(float total) {
            this.total = total;
        }

        public int setStoreCust() 
        {
            try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usermaster","admin","password");
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
            String query=null;
            query="insert into customer values(?,?,?,?,?)";
            pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1,custID);
            pstmt.setString(2,custName);
            pstmt.setInt(3,qty);
            pstmt.setFloat(4,price);
            pstmt.setFloat(5,total);
            int i=pstmt.executeUpdate();

            this.storeCust=i;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            return storeCust;
        }
}
```